# Bash script to copy *.log files into a new directory

Tags: bash, scripting

I have some files like this:

```
2012-12-17_083213_1.log  
2012-12-17_083213_1.log_stats  
2012-12-17_083213_1.logaccount_ptr  
2012-12-17_083213_1.loginitial_ptr  
2012-12-17_083213_1.logptr  
2012-12-17_093049_2.log  
2012-12-17_093049_2.log_stats  
2012-12-17_093049_2.logaccount_ptr  
2012-12-17_093049_2.loginitial_ptr  
2012-12-17_093049_2.logptr
```

In here every 1G of data, a new file is created with the name in Year-Month-Day_HourMinuteSecond_number.log format (as you can see above).

I want to

1. Copy all *.log files to a new folder named with the format Year-Month-Day, so for these it would be named: 2012-12-17
2. `tgz` that folder
3. Send it to a server IP.

I don't know how exactly. I want it as a bash script so that I can run it every day for the newly added files.

Comment: i have tried this: # !/bin/bash  



localbakdir=/opt/me/fw1/log
  
 

mkdir
  
date +%Y-%m-%d

Comment: @jordanm 


i have tried this: # !/bin/bash localbakdir=/opt/me/fw1/log mkdir date +%Y-%m-%d

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will copy you a script to do it, but next time **do some research** first and try to write it by yourself. That is the only way to learn. And, please, don't use it without understanding it.

```
#!/bin/bash
tosend=""
for i in *.log; do
    dir=$(echo $i | awk '{split($1,a,"_"); print a[1]}');
    if [ ! -d $dir ]; then
        mkdir $dir;
    fi;
    cp $i $dir;
    tosend="$tosend\n$dir"
done
for i in $(echo -e $tosend | uniq);do
    echo Compressing $i
    tar -zcvf $i.tar.gz $i
    scp $i.tar.gz user@server
done
```

The key part is using awk to split the file name, and then keeping a list of the folders you have modified. It is not the most elegant but it works.

Note that if you copy the files, next time you run it they will be copied again. The best thing would be to move them.

Btw, I added the `uniq` part instead of adding the name to the "array" within the if because it's possible that the folders already exist when you run the script.

However, if you only wish to send the new files and you run it at midnight, this is probably the best approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
tosend=""
for i in *.log; do
    dir=$(echo $i | awk '{split($1,a,"_"); print a[1]}');
    if [ ! -d $dir ]; then
        mkdir $dir;
        tosend="$tosend\n$dir"
    fi;
    mv $i $dir;
done
for i in $tosend;do
    echo Compressing $i
    tar -zcvf $i.tar.gz $i
    scp $i.tar.gz user@server
done
```

This would only send the new **folders** (even though some of the old ones may have new files). And with the `mv` the main folder will be kept clean.

For more sophisticated/bulletproof approaches, I think rsync is the best shot.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @balkian thank you so much, ofcourse i want to understand but i am new in this and i want to learn, here I dont understand how you are checking the file name and make a directory with the same name?

Comment: Jimmy, I suggest you check [this tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) or something similar to get familiar with bash.

Comment: @balkian thank you i am reading this. but my question is that in here all *.log files are put in the new folder, what if i want all the files dated today to be put there? i mean in here 2012-12-17_083213 is my folder and then inside it i have the .log and .log_stats and etc with this name inside it?